# I want to know the meaning of below code which was written in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

One of colleague used this query, i want to know the meaning of inner select query (i.e, select 1 from table (:input_country_object)). Can anyone explain me in detail how it works.

```
Select 
       id, 
       country_name, 
       price, 
       section, 
       population, 
       diversity 
from Country co 
where exists (
               select 1 
               from table (:input_country_object) ico 
               where co.country_name = ico.country_name
              );
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The query looks somewhat bogus, because it is appears to be trying to use a bind parameter as a table name.

Comment: Yah, What was that bind parameter Tim?

Comment: `:input_country_object`

Comment: May i know how this inner query works?

Comment: The basic logic of this query is that it will return every record from the `Country` table which has a match in the second table in the subquery, that is all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I think that's a parameter that gets replaced by Oracle's SQL Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about what the inner select does, here you go:

```
select 1 
from table (:input_country_object) ico 
where co.country_name = ico.country_name
```

Your query basically just selects the value `1` if the where condition is met.

So if there is data for this condition: `where co.country_name = ico.country_name` in the `:input_country_object` table, then this select just returns `1`.

This causes the `exists (...)` part of your query to return true and therefore perform the first part of your query `Select id, country_name, price, section, population, diversity from Country co`.

So overall, the query returns you these values:

`id, country_name, price, section, population, diversity`

from your

`Country` table,

for all countries which are also in the second table

`:input_country_object`

---

`:input_country_object` itself is a variable that the SQL-Developer will fill in, or you have to assign.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code f.e. on TOAD it asks you to write `tablename` instead of `:input_country_object`

So when you write table name the query **works**.

You can see it from this image : [image]